# Help understanding how to find missing number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$12 + 12+(y*y*y) = 51$$
I tried working this out and I got that $y = 9$
using that answer I had to figure out what z is equal to $z + z +(z * y) = 25$.
Im struggling in working this out, was my answer my the previous question wrong (y) ?

Comment: Where did the $z$ come from? I don't see any $z$'s in the original equation ...

Comment: $12+12+(y\cdot y\cdot y)=51$.  We subtract $12$ from both sides twice so we only have the unknown variables on the left and known numbers on the right.  This leaves us with $y\cdot y\cdot y = 27$, or written differently $y^3=27$.  Now... what number when cubed is equal to $27$?  Note the difference between the statement $3y=27$ and the statement $y^3=27$.  You seem to have added the $y$'s together instead of multiplying them, that or misunderstand how to reduce exponents.

Comment: Are you using $*$ to denote multiplication?

Comment: We are trying to find out what number z is

Comment: Yes, and we'll get to $z$ after we finish *correctly* figuring out what $y$ is.  @MattiP. it appears to be a system of equations (*i.e. a multipart question*) where the first equation given was enough to solve for $y$ and we try to use the result in the second equation to further figure out what $z$ is.

Comment: could it be that y =3 and z = 5?

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, but I suggest you study arithmetic, multiplication, order of operations, exponents, etc before doing any *algebra*. It's easy to verify that $y=9$ doesn't work.

Comment: thanks @Adola . I think I realised y is not equal 9. I haven't done maths in 6 years, i'm trying to get my head back into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$12+12+(y\cdot y\cdot y)=51$$

Subtract $12$ from each side twice

$$y\cdot y\cdot y = 27$$

Simplify as an exponent for my own sanity...

$$y^3=27$$

Note that this is $y\cdot y\cdot y = y^3$, not $y+y+y=3y$.  Perhaps you got addition and multiplication mixed up?

From here, we can take the cubic root of each side:

$$\sqrt[3]{y^3}=\sqrt[3]{27}$$

This simplifies, the cubic root of a (*real*) number cubed is the original number, $\sqrt[3]{y^3}=y$.  As for the cubic root of $27$, well, you can use a calculator for that or you can recognize the cubic roots of several small examples.  You should hopefully be able to recognize $1^3=1, 2^3=8, 3^3=27, 4^3=64, 5^3=125$ at a minimum since these numbers occur so frequently.  The cubic root of $27$ then is the number who when cubed is equal to $27$ and is then $3$.

$$y = 3$$